# Passing Text File to Perl Script on Commandline

Tags: regex, perl

Years ago I made a simple script to remove some errant data from a simple text file.  Recently I started to see it back in the data and wasn't sure why.  The Perl script hasn't changed in 5 years, and the data input looks identical to me.

I tried testing from the commandline and it does not appear to be replacing/removing the lines as it has before.  I thought perhaps it was a CRLF issue, but that doesn't appear to be the case either.

The script is simply:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p

$_ = '' if 

# Any number of zeros 
/^[0]*\r$/ || 
# Three digits
/^\d{3}\r$/ ||
# Four digits 
/^\d{4}\r$/ ||
# Five digits 
/^\d{5}\r$/ ||
# Six digits 
/^\d{6}\r$/;
```

if I call it from the command line,

```
perl -e filter.pl input_file.txt
```

I get exactly the input file, no substitutions.  The only thing that is different is that the perl script runs inside of a bigger bash script.

Where am I off track?

Comment: I'm making this worse..  if I call it from the command line as 'perl -pe filter.pl input_file.txt' I get "Unknown regexp modifier "/t" at -e line 1, at end of line
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors."

Comment: Consider changing each `\r` to `\r?` to make the `\r` optional.  Then the regex should match lines that end with `CR + LF` as well as lines that end with just `LF`

Answer (score 6):

You want the following:

```
./filter.pl input_file.txt
```

The shebang line will make the above equivalent to the following:

```
/usr/bin/perl -p ./filter.pl input_file.txt
```

`-e` is used to pass code as a parameter instead of passing a path to a script, so it shouldn't be used here.

---

Note that

```
$_ = '' if /^[0]*\r$/ || /^\d{3}\r$/ || /^\d{4}\r$/ || /^\d{5}\r$/ || /^\d{6}\r$/;
```

simplifies to

```
$_ = '' if /^(?:0*|\d{3,6})\r$/;
```

---

Note that the script will only work on a non-Windows build of Perl with an input file with Windows line endings. Odd. Are you sure you want those `\r`?